# Div ocultos hacen espacio en el HTML

Tags: html, css

Poseo dos ventanas modales creadas con CSS unicamente

A pesar de estar ocultas hacen espacio entre el HTML, el titulo de la pagina y el contedio queda asi:

```
TITULO
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
-
CONTENIDO
```

Aqui el HTML:

```
 <div id="ocultar">
    <div class="modal-wrapper" id="popup1">
    <div class="popup-contenedor">
    <h2>Circunstancias Atenuantes</h2>
    <?php
    listaAtenuantes();
    ?>
    <a class="popup-cerrar" onclick="verificar();" href="#">ACEPTAR</a>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-wrapper" id="popup2">
    <div class="popup-contenedor">
    <h2>Circunstancias Agravantes</h2>
    <?php
    listaAgravantes();
    ?>
    <a class="popup-cerrar" onclick="verificar();" href="#">ACEPTAR</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Aqui el CSS:

```
#popup1 {
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   margin-top: -300px;
}

#popup2 {
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   margin-top: -300px;
}

#popup1:target {
   visibility:visible;
   opacity: 1;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
   position: fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   margin:0;
   z-index: 999;
   -webkit-transition:all 1s;
   -moz-transition:all 1s;
   transition:all 1s;
}

#popup2:target {
   visibility:visible;
   opacity: 1;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
   position: fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   margin:0;
   z-index: 999;
   -webkit-transition:all 1s;
   -moz-transition:all 1s;
   transition:all 1s;
}

.popup-contenedor {
   position: relative;
   margin:7% auto;
   padding:30px 50px;
   background-color: #fafafa;
   color:#333;
   border-radius: 3px;
   width:50%;
}
a.popup-cerrar {
   position: absolute;
   top:3px;
   right:3px;
   background-color: #333;
   padding:7px 10px;
   font-size: 20px;
   text-decoration: none;
   line-height: 1;
   color:#fff;
}
```

Como puedo evitar que hagan tanto espacio

**CSS MODIFICADO**

```
#popup1 {
   display: none;
   opacity: 0;
   margin-top: -300px;
}

#popup2 {
   display: none;
   opacity: 0;
   margin-top: -300px;
}

#popup1:target {
   display: block;
   opacity: 1;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   margin:0;
   z-index: 999;
   -webkit-transition:all 1s;
   -moz-transition:all 1s;
   transition:all 1s;
}

#popup2:target {
   display: block;
   opacity: 1;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
   position: absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   margin:0;
   z-index: 999;
   -webkit-transition:all 1s;
   -moz-transition:all 1s;
   transition:all 1s;
}

.popup-contenedor {
   position: absolute;
   margin:7% auto;
   padding:30px 50px;
   background-color: #fafafa;
   color:#333;
   border-radius: 3px;
   width:50%;
}
a.popup-cerrar {
   position: absolute;
   top:3px;
   right:3px;
   background-color: #333;
   padding:7px 10px;
   font-size: 20px;
   text-decoration: none;
   line-height: 1;
   color:#fff;
}
```

Ya no hacen espacio, pero al mostrarse salen pegadas a la izquierda, no centrado

Comment: cambia visibility: hidden; por display:none;

Comment: Si son modales deberían estar posicionadas con `position: absolute` y centradas. Una modal se sitúa "encima" del resto de elementos para representar una mayor importancia que el resto.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En primer lugar, y como ya te dijeron, la propiedad `visibility` solo oculta el elemento dentro del árbol, pero este nunca desaparece, siempre sigue estando allí y ocupando un espacio como cualquier caja. Para esto propósito puedes usar `display: none`.

Sin embargo, las buenas prácticas en experiencia de usuario (UX) recomiendan que una modal debe ser absoluta y tener una relevancia mayor en el stack de elementos. Es decir, una modal **representa mayor importancia o urgencia** en una aplicación.

```
.modal-wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#popup1, #popup2 {
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  transform: translateX(-50%); /* centra horizontalmente */
  z-index: 10; /* mientras más, más arriba en la pila se mostrará */
}
```

---

**Ejemplo de una modal**

Aquí te pongo un ejemplo de cómo debe verse una modal para mantener el foco de atención en ella. Es importante que sea fija para que aunque se haga scroll la modal siempre esté visible y el usuario no pierda el contacto con ella.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans:400,700');
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Noto Sans';
  height: 500vh;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.modal {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  width: 90%;
  z-index: 5;
}

.modal-header,
.modal-footer {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  padding: 0 12px;
}

.modal-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.modal-header h4 {
  color: #777;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 15px;
}

.modal-body h3 {
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
}

.modal-footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  text-align: right;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #555;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0 12px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.btn.danger {
  background-color: #ff0065;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn.danger:hover {
  background-color: #ff3d8b;
}

.btn.danger:active {
  background-color: f20061;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-wrapper">
  <div class="modal">
    <header class="modal-header">
      <h4>Atención</h4>
    </header>
    <article class="modal-body">
      <h3>¿Seguro que desea eliminar los mensajes?</h3>
    </article>
    <footer class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn">
        Cancel
      </button>
      <button class="btn danger">
        Delete
      </button>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 para `display: none`

Comment: ya me sale encima de los elementos en el principio del documento, pero no se donde colocar el display:none;tengo este script que se ejecuta con bodyonload

function refrescado() {
document.getElementById("#popup1").display:none;
document.getElementById("#popup2").display:none;
}

Pero no los oculta

Comment: ¿En dónde has visto que los elementos tengan una propiedad `display`? Además, ¿por qué no miras la consola del navegador? Si la miraras vieras **que hay un error de sintaxis**: los dos puntos se usan con objetos. Para editar los estilos de un elemento se hace mediante `style`: `$('#popup1').style.display = 'none;` o si usas jQuery: `${'#popup1').css('display', 'none');`.

Answer (score 4):

La propiedad **visibility** oculta los elementos pero siguen ocupando el espacio dentro de la estructura de tu HTML. Como te indicaron antes, cambia esta propiedad por `display: none`, que también oculta los elementos pero no conserva el espacio.

Comment: ya agregue el tag de visibiliy, pero ahora me aparecen en un lado, no centrado

Comment: Tienes que remplazar visibility por display: none, no agregarselo.

Comment: publcare el cambio para que veas,